# Should I need delete or after close?

Tags: c++, forms, qt, user-interface, widget

I have a form (inherited from QMainWindow) with "Settings" button that need to show settings form (inherited from QWidget).

Button click() connected with some settingsButtonClick() slot

And in settingsButtonClick:

```
void MainQT::settingsButtonClick()
{
    SettingsForm *settingsForm = new settingsForm();
    settingsForm->show();
}
```

It works properly, but question is should I need delete this form somewhere or it would be deleted when I close settings form?
What i correct way to manage memory in this case? Should I instantiate settings form in MainForm's ctor hidden and only show on request?

Comment: You would need to `delete` it manually. But why `new` it in the first place? Why not just `SettingsForm settingsForm; settingsform.show();`?

Comment: @BoBTFish because in your case, form will be destroyed immideatly after showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
void MainQT::settingsButtonClick()
{
    SettingsForm *settingsForm = new settingsForm();
    settingsForm->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
    settingsForm->show();
}
```

Using `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` will make sure that the `settingsForm` will be deleted after you closing it.
For more details take a look into [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum).

Answer (score 0):

> should I delete this form somewhere or it would be deleted when I close settings form? What is the correct way to manage memory in this case? Should I instantiate settings form in MainForm's ctor hidden and only show on request?

There are no strict rules for this, you may:

- create Settings dialog each time you need to display it and then destroy the object;
- create Settings dialog in MainForm constructor and then just display it upon user action;
- you may even use Settings dialog as a contrainer to store settings values

Please just note that your code creates new object and never destroys it, which would result in memory leak; consider saving pointer as member variable and re-use it if user opens Settings dialog another time:

```
void MainQT::settingsButtonClick()
{
    if(!mSettingsForm) mSettingsForm = new settingsForm();
    settingsForm->show();
}
```